Azure Frontdoor - rewrite url with updated subdomain and new domain
I have web apps with names like "apps--dw", "qa01--dw", etc.
These can be created on the fly (out of my control). Only the "--dw" bit is fixed, the rest of the name can be any letters/numbers.
They have the default urls "apps--dw.azurewebsites.net", etc.
These web apps need to be accessible using one domain "mydomain.com" via the subdomain.
Requests for "apps.mydomain.com" will go to web app "apps--dw" at "apps--dw.azurewebsites.net",
requests for "qa01.mydomain.com" to web app "qa01--dw" at "qa01--dw.azurewebsites.net", etc.
I'm using one Azure Frontdoor profile in front of all these web apps. It uses "mydomain.com" as the custom domain.
How can I create a URL Rewrite rule(s) in Azure Frontdoor to create the above mapping?
If this is not possible, what would be a good alternative approach?

"URL Rewriting" generally refers to changes to the path (and sometimes the query) part of a URI - not the host (or authority) parts, because that's just Host:-based routing. So you don't even need Azure Front Door for this either: just have an ARM job that binds apps.mydomain.com directly to apps--dw via its Host: ("custom domain") bindings. If you do want to use Azue Front Door for this, then I imagine you'll want a separate profile for each website/subdomain - but you won't need any routing or WAF policies within each profile (except to directly map request-paths 1:1).
